# Browser caching images served from the AWS Serverless Image Handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

The Cloudformation template "Serverless Image Handler" by AWS is nice, but the images do not seem to cache automatically in the browser.

Do you know where to set this so that the same URL is not downloaded again, at least during the same session? I'm using the same image on two different screens of a single page app and it always just redownloads. There should effectively be no second HTTP request, not even to check an ETag or something.

The setup uses a Cloudfront distribution, a Lambda function that does the resizing, API Gateway, and S3 as image storage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, there is an open pull request to fix this on Github.

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/pull/158